Share identity cookie across subdomains
My ASP.NET Core Blazor application is themed by subdomain, but I don't want users to have to sign each time they visit the site on a different subdomain.
The cookie configuration is as follows:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityCookies();

If I visit the site at myappdomain.com and sign in, then I visit the same app with sub.myappdomain.com, then I have to sign in again. I'm surprised by this, as I thought that the browser would apply the cookie to the subdomain site, based on the domain name:

However, if I edit the domain of the cookie to have a . prefix, ie. .myappdomain.com, then the cookie works as expected.
There are a few similar questions on here from years ago whose answers don't seem to map well to my configuration.
Does anyone know how I can configure the identity cookie to include subdomains?

if you leave out the domain attribute of a cookie it will be set for that domain or subdomain only.   It's counter-intuitive but leaving out the domain when setting the cookie is actually more restrictive than setting it.  If you set the domain explicitly for your main domain, those cookies will be sent to the main domain and any/all subdomains.

The reverse is not true.  So setting cookies from subdomain to subdomain.maindomain.com, would not send those cookies to the main domain, but would send them to subdomains of the subdomain...  You can instead set them to the main domain and they would be shared.  Probably don't want to include ".", just use the main domain.   Seems like that would share across subdomains but not necessarily main domain.  (maindomain.com doesn't seem like a match... though maybe www.maindomain.com would?... all subdomains would match though)

You could try follow this document:
 builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(op =>
{
    .......
    op.Cookie.Domain = ".myappdomain.com";
    
});

